# 12 V battery charging problem

Tags: power-supply

I fly a glider in which I would like to install a 12 V 15 Ah LiFePo battery to replace the current lead acid battery. Currently charging is done from the load output of a solar charge controller through a smart DC to DC charger and then to the glider battery. My problem stems from the fact the Gliding Federation only approves one particular battery for use in gliders in Australia (FUSION V-LFP-12-15). The manufacturer states that the battery has an internal battery management system and should not be charged with a smart charger. Doing so will damage the battery. I thought of just using my current setup for a lead acid battery but the smart charger sees that the new battery is LiFePo and tries to charge it using that protocol. What I really need is a wall wart type charger that will run from 12 V DC (aka dumb charger) but I cannot find such a thing. They are all 220 V AC to 12 V DC and I do not have access to mains power at my hangar. Would a boost converter connected to the load output of the solar charge controller and adjusted for a constant voltage of say 14.4 V work for charging this battery? I have been advised that the charge current should be about 10% of the battery capacity (so 1.5 A) but I do not know if a boost converter has adjustable current output as well as voltage regulation. From what I have read I don't think so. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So is the approved battery the one you want to fit? If not are you expecting us to help you break the regulations?

Comment: The kind of charger that is normally used with the FUSION V-LFP-12-15 appears to be [this one](https://www.batteriesdirect.com.au/shop/product/26617/Selectable%201800mA/7000mA%20fully%20automatic%20battery%20charger%20(12V%20Lead%20Acid)%20(14.4-14.8V%20Lithium%20Ion/Polymer)%20(12.8V%20Lithium%20Iron%20Phosphate).html). (Per what I read [here](https://www.batteriesdirect.com.au/shop/product/24486/v-lfp-12-15.html).) It's not a dumb device and is, instead, a multistep charger. Can't you provide it with the input AC voltage through an inverter operating from whatever power source you do have?

Comment: The literature for the battery states "Fusion Lithium Batteries do not require special Lithium chargers or charging systems. Instead our Lithium batteries can be charged using most normal 12V sealed lead acid battery chargers".  " Do not use a smart charger or any charger with pulse charging for this battery." That is why I have arrived at the boost converter as a possible solution but I know little about them.  But if the boost converter will work it is a low cost solution to my problem.  Or maybe there is something else that  will work .That is what I really want to know.

Comment: @raymo The one added piece of information you provided in a comment that I consider important is that the cost of the inverter exceeds the budget. That's fine. I didn't know any better when I wrote. Now I do. There are two paths ahead, neither of which I'm willing to work on for you. (1) Dig deeper into precise details about what the battery 'wants' (since a multistage charger is recommended, this warns me it is not as simple as "a voltage source" and I'd need to find proof that it could be.) (2) Or search for something that meets your budget and other unknown to me requirements. So I'm done.

Comment: Periblepsis. thanks for your input. After reading your advice I got in touch with the manufacturers technical department to ask them what charge profile was needed. Probably should have started there in the first place (my bad). They have confirmed that a constant voltage constant current voltage supply would be fine and the internal battery management system will look after the charging profile. they even supplied me with the correct current and voltage specs so all good.

Comment: @raymo This is `very very good news` to hear. I'm so glad you took a moment to contact them, too. That was the right thing to do. And you did it!!! That alone generates so much respect from me to you. I'd hire you, now. Good work! Best wishes looking forward! (But I know you won't need them. You have made an impression and I'm sure you will be just fine on your own. And thanks for letting me know what you did. It's really nice to see it happen from time to time. If and when you ever need further help, I'll remember this and be willing to try harder.)

Answer (score 0):

If all the balancing, overvoltage and undervoltage protection is inside of the battery, then you can chose simply a ordinare powersupply.

They write on their website:
"Each battery is equipped with an Internal Battery Management System (BMS) for cell balancing and added protection."

Which output voltage should you use?

A 12V LIFePO4 battery contains 4 cells.

- Minimum voltage: 4x3.2V = 12.8V
- Maximum voltage: 4x3.65V = 14.6V

Possibly 14.6V as maximum. At least over 13.8V so that the balancing-mechanism of the battery can start to work.

(I would use the cells in an area of 3.3V-3.45V per cell.)

StepUp-Converter: [LTC3780](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/32902533475.html)
You can find these type of stepup/down regulators at Aliexpress for 8,30€ + 2,80€ shipping.

It is possible to use this StepUp-regulator on a solar panel. For this you have to set the UV-Set poti to the average max-powerpoint voltage of the PV-module. This is not perfect, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am going to use a suitable buck /boost converter with constant voltage and current regulation set to 14.6v and 1.5 amps as per manufacturers advice.

Comment: @raymo - Okay, but this device can deliver up to 7A and should work in the desired way.